# Building x86 APKs with Kivy / Buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

The ARM Android emulator is 10x or more slower than the x86 emu. If you search around, you will find that in the past, people had trouble building x86 APKs using buildozer because I think maybe p4a didn't support it yet. However, I have a feeling that maybe now it does. In the [p4a docs](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/), you can see a directive for `--arch`. Is there a way to pass x86 as the arch to buildozer to get an x86 apk?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `android.arch` config token in buildozer.spec.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it as x86 is not working on Google play yet (even if you can upload the file on it).

Comment: They're looking to emulate it locally, not upload the x86 binary to Google Play.